# Let user '_www' execute binary in /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, php

Total *nix n00b, so I apologize in advance.
I installed ffmpeg through homebrew, now I want to call it from a PHP script with `shell_exec()`, e.g. `ffmpeg -v`. But nothing is happening. From Terminal it runs just fine.

Apache is executing as `_www`, so I figured it wouldn’t have sufficient permissions to find anything inside `/usr/local/bin`. So I placed a symlink to the ffmpeg binary in `/usr/bin`. Nothing. I can run `which ffmpeg` but that only gives me `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`. Calling `ffmpeg -version` outputs nothing.

I checked that the permissions on ffmpeg are set to 755, but that had no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the PHP-FFmpeg library to do ffmpeg things.

It is available here: [The PHP-FFMpeg library](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip, eventually I might have to resort to this solution. But still looking forward to a solution that’s not extension-based.

Comment: This still requires the binaries to be executable via PHP, so it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be totry to run the command as _www-user by calling sudo -u _www -H [command]

That would run [command] as _www-User so you can see what happens on terminal.

But there might be a simpler solution. The _www-User might simply not have /usr/local/bin in his PATH-variable. Therefore you will have to call /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg in your script instead of ffmpeg and everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that ffmpeg does not output to `stdout`. If you call it, you need to either capture `stderr`, or redirect it.

So, run:

```
ffmpeg -v 2&>1
```